# Composite rule of Newton cotes? Simpson + Trapzoid

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, extrapolation, simpsons-rule

**What is the best combination of Trapezoidal rule and Simpson's rule to solve this problem?**

I used:

Trapz from 1 to 2

1/3 Simpson's from 2 to 4.5

Trapz from 4.5 to 6

3/8 Simpson's from 6 to 9

1/3 Simpson's from 9 to 10

**My answer is: 71.05175**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the best? Given finite values, I don't think there is a way to know what will work better, am I missing something?

Comment: I tried different combinations and they give a range of values between 50 to about 70. I'm not sure which one to choose or would be closer to the real value?

Comment: Without knowing more than we know here, I think there is no real value, or way of choosing which to use.